# USPS Tracking API Issue with XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm new to web development. I was trying to make a call to USPS Tracking API using XMLHttpRequest. Eventhough, I'm able to get the response when I paste below URL into address bar, I'm not able to get any response with code.

```
http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPITest.dll?API=TrackV2&XML=<TrackRequest USERID="xxxxxx"><TrackID ID="EJ958083578US"></TrackID></TrackRequest>
```

This is the code I was trying:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = handleStateChange;
xhr.open("GET","http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPITest.dll?API=TrackV2&XML=<TrackRequest USERID='xxxxxx'><TrackID ID='EJ958083578US'></TrackID></TrackRequest>" , isAsync);
xhr.send();
```

Comment: You can't make a cross domain request like that in JavaScript.

Comment: If you the server responded with the right [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Origin) header, you could do cross-domain from javascript, however I haven't figured out how to get the server to send back the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` for the source..

Answer (score -1):

It will not work with "GET", use "POST". It will work.